# Create plot from .ncdf data in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a NetCDF file of salinity in Indonesia water with 4 dimension (lon, lat, depth and time). I would like to create a map from my data, but it's appear not in appropriate position that not exactly match with the coastline.
download data here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6FFDD661570C7D0A%21177
output map here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6FFDD661570C7D0A%21176

```
# This is my script
library (ncdf)
library (raster)
library (sp)

setwd ('D:/work')
bio <- open.ncdf('data.nc')
print (bio)

sal.dat <- get.var.ncdf(bio,"salinity")
sal0 <- brick(sal.dat[,,1,])
extent(sal0) <- c(105,110,-5,0)
projection(sal0) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

#plot image
image (sal0)

# load coastal lines of Indonesia:
con <- url("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/R/IDN_adm0.RData")
load(file = con)
close(con)

# plot coastal lines:
plot(gadm, add = T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rasterVis` package for that purpose:

```
# load needed librairies
library(rasterVis)
library(rgeos)

# open the data
salinity <- brick("data.nc", varname = "salinity")

# load coastal lines of Indonesia:
con <- url("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/R/IDN_adm0.RData")
load(file = con)
close(con)

# clip the coastline to the study area
CP <- as(extent(salinity), "SpatialPolygons")
proj4string(CP) <- CRS(proj4string(gadm))
gadm <- gIntersection(gadm, CP, byid=TRUE)

# map
levelplot(subset(salinity, 1), margin = FALSE) +
layer(sp.polygons(gadm, fill='transparent', col='black'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond - Pascal

Comment: @pascal..You a right and i have another question. Could you give an easy way how to make a composite from 5 layer in this data? so i can get 5-day composite of salinity in this region..what i do is convert the raster into vector and the use apply to get the mean, but i have problem to plot the vector data into map like before...

Comment: Please explore the functions of the `raster` package, such as `calc`, `cellStats` or `overlay`.

Comment: a simple question about hoe to define the fix value for color ramp, i want to display all this data with range 10-60. I tried to use **at** but still not working **levelplot(subset(salinity, 1), contour=T, at=seq(10, 60, 5), margin=FALSE)**

Comment: a simple question about hoe to define the fix value for color ramp, i want to display all this data with range 10-60. I tried to use **at** but still not working **levelplot(subset(salinity, 1), contour=T, at=seq(20, 33, 1), margin=FALSE)**

Comment: Can you clarify "still not working". What do you mean? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to setup the minimum and maximum value of the colorramp between (20-34 psu).

Comment: It doesn't clarify "still not working". What is not working? What do you get? You probably should ask you new question clearly indicating your problem.

Comment: So sorry my English not very good..based on the first picture we saw that the range of the data is from 18-33 psu, but i just want to show the range is 20-34psu, because for each layer have different minimum and maximum value. I hope it's more clearly